# Apache Spark (local mode) throws FileNotFoundException when writing files to local file system

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save multiple datasets across multiple threads to my local file system with spark running in local mode.

When I try to save the datasets as JSON to my local file system a FileNotFoundException is thrown saying, that the `_temporary` directory no longer exists.
My understanding of the issue is that, as soon as multiple instances try to perform operations in the `_temporary` directory created by Spark or Hadoop, the implemented FileOutputCommitter
fails to handle it.

I have tried changing the `spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version` to `version 2`. The only effect this parameter had, is that I could start more threads, but at around 50 threads the FileNotFoundException came up again, thus not solving the underlying issue.

I also tried using a ConcurrentLinkedQueue to queue up the requests, which led me to synchronize my `provokeException` method. This "solution" performed badly and does not play well with my applications requirements.

Then I tried overwriting the FileOutputCommitter. I tried to apply this example(https://www.outbrain.com/techblog/2020/03/how-you-can-set-many-spark-jobs-write-to-the-same-path/) to my code, but Spark ignored the CustomFileOutputCommitter and kept throwing a FileNotFoundException under load. Since I do not use Kafka or work directly with Hadoop, I do not know how to use the `MultipleTextOutputFormat` (mentioned in the example) with my `Dataset` implementation.

I am using Spark version 3.1.1
The application is a java spring-boot application

Here is my code to hopefully easily reproduce my error:

First up the java object I am trying to save:

```
@Data
public class SparkTestData {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Long group;

    public SparkTestData(Long id, String name, String description, Long group) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.group = group;
    }
}
```

Then my class for generating data:

```
@Service
public class SparkController implements ISparkController {

    @Override
    public void provokeException(long listSize, long amountOfLists) {

        List<List<SparkTestData>> testDataList = new LinkedList<>();

        for (long i = 0; i < amountOfLists; i++) {
            List<SparkTestData> sparkTestDataList = new LinkedList<>();
            for (long j = 0; j < listSize; j++) {
                sparkTestDataList
                        .add(new SparkTestData(i, "name_" + j, "datalist_" + i + ". Entry: " + j, i));
            }
            testDataList.add(sparkTestDataList);
        }

        for (List<SparkTestData> sparkTestDataList : testDataList) {
            new Thread(new SparkWriter(sparkTestDataList)).start();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the class that writes the spark files:

```
@Slf4j
public class SparkWriter implements Runnable {

    private final List<SparkTestData> sparkTestDataList;

    public SparkWriter(List<SparkTestData> sparkTestDataList) {
        this.sparkTestDataList = sparkTestDataList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        writeData();
    }

    private void writeData() {

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .getOrCreate();

        log.info("Spark version: {}", spark.version());

        String outputPathString = "./spark-test";

        Encoder<SparkTestData> sparkTestDataEncoder = Encoders.bean(SparkTestData.class);

        Dataset<SparkTestData> dataset = spark.createDataset(sparkTestDataList, sparkTestDataEncoder);

        log.info("Created dataset {}", dataset);
        dataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).option("nullValue", null).partitionBy("group").json(outputPathString);
        log.info("Finished writing data for list");
    }
}
```

All that being said, how do I prevent this issue from happening?

- Do I have to write my own FileOutputCommitter and if so, how do I tell Spark or Hadoop to use my custom committer ?
- Am I missing some Spark configuration parameter specific to a local file system and Spark running in local mode?
- Is my thread approach wrong for Spark? If thats the case how to I maintain performance when writing a lot files?

### EDIT

It turns out I had some misconceptions about Spark.
Spark is not meant to be run on multiple threads. There is only ever one spark session present at any given moment, so my thread approach artificially creates a problem that was never meant to be handled by Spark.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Emer I am using macOS Catalina version 10.15.7.

Comment: @Emer PS: The same behaviour occures on RHEL 7.6